# Example- $l_p$ norm space

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, self-learning

$$||x||= {[{\sum _{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^p}]}^{1/p}$$
Is a norm on $l_p$ space :- space of all sequences made of scalars from $\mathfrak C$(filed of complex numbers).

To prove that above is norm on $l_p$ space; firstly, we need to show that $||x||\ge0$.[first property of norm space]

It is written in my book that this is trivially. But I couldn't convince myself.

Here $x=<x_1,x_2........>$ sequences, where scalars $x_i\in \mathfrak C$, So $|x_i|>0$ and their sum is positive. But its whole power is $1/p$ then how come its always positive. for example if $p= 1/2$ then $||x||$ has two values one is positive and another negative.

Comment: The positive root is *taken*.

Comment: why do they ignore negative one?

Comment: Because we want that $\|\ \|$ *be* a norm.

Comment: Still, I am not convinced. when there are two or more possible values of ||x|| then how can we ignore negative one?

Comment: It is not mentioned to ignore negative values in the definition of norm. right! We want to prove that it cann't be negative. And here we are forcing it to get positive value.

Comment: There are **no** several possible values of $\|\ \|$ because whe **choose** the positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context (and quite generally in the context of analysis) $x^\alpha $ for non-negative $x$ is assumed to be the non-negative value of $x^\alpha $ (in case more than one value is possible). So, in particular, $x^{1/2}$ means the non-negative square root of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)\in \ell_p$, then as $|x_i|\geq 0$, $\forall i$, we have that $|x_i|^p\geq 0$, $\forall i$ and $\forall p$, then $\sum |x_i|^p \geq 0$ and so
$$||x||=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\geq 0. $$

Comment: How do we know that $p$th root of that sum will be positive? :(